# Why is the op-amp not regulating voltage in this circuit?

Tags: operational-amplifier, measurement, current-source, constant-current

I'm a first timer here, I hope I can explain my problem as clearly as possible.

I need to apply a current source to measure the voltage on a load for a given current. Since I don't really have many components, I used what I had on hand. The circuit in the image is the one I made on a breadboard. It works, I used a potentiometer to change the reference voltage and get different currents, checked with an ammeter. The problem is, I can't get the current lower than a certain value.

I crank up the (-) voltage of the op amp to the source voltage (8 V), while the (+) voltage, at the drain of the MOSFET, is lower than that by about 1 V, but the op-amp does not saturate. I would expect the output voltage to go down if that were the case, but it stays at about 3 V, which coincidentaly is about the threshold value of the transistor... I don't know if it has to do anything with that.

Basically, I can't get the voltage difference across the reference resistor to be lower than 1 V, because the op-amp isn't working as expected (at least not as I expect): The (-) voltage is higher than the (+) voltage by a considerable amount (1 V or higher), but it's not saturating the output at the minimum possible voltage (It's at aroung 3 V while it should be less than 0.5 V). The op-amp is connected to source voltage and ground, I don't use negative voltage.

I used an oscilloscope to check if there were any oscilations that could have been messing with the readings on my multimeter, but it was perfectly constante voltage.

[image]

I'm using a LM358P as op-amp, and a P40NF03L as the MOSFET. Rg provides stability and the Rref was 1Kohm to provide a low current for testing, but the final design has to handle about 300 mA, which shouldn't be a problem at all for the MOSFET used. The load tested ranged from short circuit to ground to a few hundreds ohm.

UPDATE: I tried reducing the feedback voltage range, as Audioguru suggested, with a resistor divider and it worked!

Comment: What range of current do you want? What are the details of your power supply rails? What kind of precision and repeatability from build to build to you need to achieve? What kind of repeatable accuracy is required (assuming vref-in is perfectly known, to current out?) ANd over what ambient temperature range? More information is always better.

Comment: The old LM358 inputs do not work when they are within 1.5V from its power supply voltage. The inputs of a TL081 work at the power supply voltage but not within 2V to 4V from your ground. You need a modern rail-to-rail opamp.

Comment: @jonk
Current: 0 mA to be turned off by a microcontroller, maybe with a transistor used as a switch, to about 300 mA

Power supply: It's suppoused to use a Li-Ion battery at about 7 V. For testing I used a lab bench PS with the same voltage


Precicion and repeatability: I can spend as much time as needed calibrating this. I only need one build

Temperature: Ambient temperature, but from winter to summer I guess it can go from 15ºC to over 40ºC indoors. That's not considering heating from the current itself, but it shouldn't be an issue since it's not going to be running constantly

Comment: @Audioguru I see! If that's the case maybe I can try adapting the (+) input with a voltage divider from the drain so it doesn't need to go to such high voltages. That would take some current from the load, but it shouldn't be a big deal. I can use a buffer if it is I guess

Comment: @IvánCarello Need bipolar current or unipolar, as shown above? Is the control voltage fully adjustable over the needed range? What is the control voltage range, exactly?

Comment: Have you observed operation with a scope? In addition to the problems others have commented on I would expect instability with the extra gain of the MOSFET. As designed the control voltage is referred to the positive rail.

Comment: @KevinWhite I did mention in the post that I used an oscilloscope, paragraph over the image